# JQuery el efecto del menu funciona solo una vez

Tags: jquery, css, menú, animación

http://www.maytelabargamalaga.com/prueba-menu/index.html

Hola a todos. Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

En el enlace que he adjuntado, estoy intentando animar la barra de menu. La idea es que cada vez que se pulse en un enlace, la barra desaparezca completamente y vuelva a aparecer.

Problemas:
La animacion se hace una vez al inicio y luego no se repite. ¿quizas sea porque no he conseguido quitar la clase ('desaparece) o por la posicion fija del objeto?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menu menu--antonio header-nav-wrap">
                <ul class="menu__list header-nav">
                    <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#home" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="uno">Starseite</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="dos">Über mich</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#interactive" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="tres">Interaktiv</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#course" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cuartro">Coaching</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#kontakt" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cinco">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__line"></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

**JS (JQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $allDocument = $(window);
    $desplazamiento = $('.smoothscroll');
    var cabecera = $('.main-header');

    $desplazamiento.click(function(e){     

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).stop().offset().top 
        },1500);

        cabecera.addClass('desaparece');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.desaparece {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
-moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Lo que veo es que solo desaparece con el primer enlace (über mich) pero sí que vuelve a aparecer. Con el resto simplemente no desaparece

Comment: Hola Mayte, recuerda que siempre debes incluir en las preguntas un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Para así entender cual es el inconveniente en si y poder reproducirlo, de otra manera no es practico y tu pregunta no resulta atractiva. Observa como [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para que en el futuro tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que las animaciones en CSS no se pueden reiniciar simplemente añadiendo de nuevo la clase.

Te recomiendo leer [este](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) artículo con varias alternativas, [este](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/01/restart-css-animation-using-css-to-trigger-a-reflow/) otro (basado en el anterior y con una solución alternativa), [este](https://blog.timhagn.com/restart-css3-animations-on-hover-without-javascript/) otro (con otra solución) y [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element) pregunta.

He implementado una de ellas (del primer artículo) en la que se elimina y añade de nuevo la clase. La clave está en que, entre medias, llama a `void this.offsetWidth;` que fuerza al navegador a recalcular el elemento del DOM (Reflow) y se reinicia así la animación. [Aquí](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) más info.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $allDocument = $(window);
    $desplazamiento = $('.smoothscroll');
    var cabecera = $('.main-header');


    $desplazamiento.click(function(e){       

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).stop().offset().top 
        },1500);

        //Eliminamos la clase "desaparece"
        cabecera.removeClass("desaparece");   
        //Forzamos el reflow del elemento con offsetWidth
        void this.offsetWidth;
        //Volvemos a añadir la clase para reiniciar la animación
        cabecera.addClass("desaparece");          
    });
}
```

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Kikp_L. Mil mil gracias. Eres un genio. Wow!!! funciona perfectamente. Tomo muy en cuenta tus sugerencias y leere esos articulos. Son super utiles. Muchas muchas gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score -1):

Vale, identificar el problema en la pagina resulta poco practico ya que no es un sand-box adecuado, para tu próxima pregunta, podrías incluir el problema en un fiddle para que se pueda hacer un testeo correcto y a de mas cabe decir que es algo completamente posible con la herramienta de fragmento de código de Stack.

Pasando a la pregunta en cuestión, creo que el error radica a que estas trabajando una animación con css, te seria mas practico si lo hicieras todo con JQuery, de la siguiente manera:

> Con fadeIn y fadeOut

```js
$("nav ul li").click(function(){

  $("nav").fadeOut();
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    $("nav").fadeIn();
  
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0;

}

body {

  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;


}

nav {

  width: 100%;

}

nav ul {

  height: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

nav ul li {

  display: inline-flex;

}

nav ul li a {

  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;

}

nav ul li a:hover {

  color: white;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu menu--antonio header-nav-wrap">
                <ul class="menu__list header-nav">
                    <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#home" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="uno" >Starseite</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="dos" >Über mich</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#interactive" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="tres" >Interaktiv</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#course" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cuartro" >Coaching</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#kontakt" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cinco">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__line"></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

> Con visibility y opacity:

```js
$("nav ul li").click(function(){

  $("nav").css({"visibility": "hidden","opacity": "0"});
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    $("nav").css({"visibility": "visible","opacity": "1"});
  
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0;

}

body {

  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;


}

nav {

  width: 100%;
  transition: .2s; /*agrego un transition*/

}

nav ul {

  height: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

nav ul li {

  display: inline-flex;

}

nav ul li a {

  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;

}

nav ul li a:hover {

  color: white;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu menu--antonio header-nav-wrap">
                <ul class="menu__list header-nav">
                    <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#home" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="uno" >Starseite</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="dos" >Über mich</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#interactive" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="tres" >Interaktiv</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#course" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cuartro" >Coaching</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#kontakt" class="menu__link smoothscroll" id="cinco">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__line"></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

La diferencia entre los dos métodos es principalmente la permanencia en la pagina, si usas `fadeIn()` y `fadeOut()` es como le adjudicaras al elemento la propiedad css `display: none`; en cambio si utilizas directamente las propiedades `visibility` y `opacity` solo estas colocando al elemento entero transparente.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!